# Gradle keeps on running without loading the project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am developing a very simple Android-App on `Android-Studio` that creates XML-CAP-Formated file. Currently, I am using `xmlSerializer`. However, I want ot use Google CAP Library ([The Common Alerting Protocol Library](https://github.com/google/cap-library)). I downloaded the source from git, generated the `CapLibrary.jar` file. Then, I added the library to my project as follow:

1. Create a folder named `libs` in `MyProject->app` folder
2. Copy and paste the `CapLibrary.jar` file to the `libs` folder
3. Right-click on the `CapLibrary.jar` file and select `Add As Library...`

Now when I try to use the library and run my application I get this error:

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>       Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
>       This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
>       If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
>       targetCompatibility = '1.7'
>       sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
>       to that submodule's build.gradle file.

So, I added the following two lines to `build.gradle`:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

But Again it gives me this error:

> Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either
>   enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.

So, to enable Jack, I added the following line:

```
defaultConfig {
    .
    .
    .
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
```

Now, when I again try to run my application, it doesn't do anything. I mean the `Gradle Build Running` keep on loading, stopping at `Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]`:

[image]

So, I don't know why is it not loading the poject, am I importing the library in the right way ?! or is it somthing to do with Java 1.8 ?!